# Read from 2 XML files using StreamReader

Tags: c#, serialization

Assuming I have the following XML files:

---

Sample1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
   <NodeA>
      <Node1>test1</Node1>
      <Node1>test2</Node1>
   </NodeA>
</Root>
```

Sample2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
   <NodeB>
      <Node1>test1</Node1>
      <Node1>test2</Node1>
   </NodeB>
</Root>
```

---

My goal is to deserialize those 2 xml files using one factory method.

For that I have the following generic code:

```
    public static T get<T>() where T : class // class = all reference types
            {
                string Ttype = typeof(T).Name;
                using (var streamReader1 = new StreamReader(directoryPath + @"\Sample1.xml"))
                using (var streamReader2 = new StreamReader(directoryPath + @"\Sample2.xml"))
                using (var xmlReader ??? = XmlReader.Create(streamReader))
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Built both xml files with the same root element.

My question is, since the xmlReader create function accepts only 1 stream reader. 
 How in the name of *, do i read with the xml reader from 2 xmls?

Do I combine 2 streams into 1 and read from 1st bit to the last 1, if so, how?

Thanks in advance,

Montana.

Comment: You cannot do what you're asking.  It's that simple.  If you edit the question to explain your ultimate goal, we can give you some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);
            XElement root1 = (XElement)doc1.FirstNode;

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);
            XElement root2 = (XElement)doc2.FirstNode;

            root1.Add(root2.Elements());
        }

    }
}
```